# RMarkdown: Add a box around a kable table

Tags: r-markdown, knitr, kableextra

This is I'm sure a very simple problem that belies my lack of understanding of kable / css

I'm making a simple kable, e.g.

```
kable(mtcars)
```

I'd love it to have a border around the whole table and the caption, with some white space between the border and its contents.

I've achieved this with the css code:

```
table {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

But there are two problems:

1. I'd like the caption to be inside of the box
2. There's no space between the table and the box - I thought padding would address this

I've tried an outline with an offset:

```
table {
  outline:1px solid black;
  outline-offset: 20px;
}
```

But then my text wraps too tight, and the box cuts over it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a div block, e.g.

````
---
title: "Title"
output: html_document
---


:::{.border style="padding: 10px; border: 1px solid #dee2e6 !important;"}
```{r}
#| echo: false
mtcars[1:5,] |> kableExtra::kbl(caption = "Caption") |> kableExtra::kable_styling()
```
:::
````

[image]

Comment: That's excellent. I wonder why the document is refusing to render the borders from the css file?